# RecyclerView - control item count by boolean

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I'm using a `RecyclerView` where there is a boolean involved in `getItemCount()`. This boolean value controls the visibility of the last item in the `RecyclerView`, kinda like a load more view, but slightly different. From time to time, the value of this boolean changes, so the `RecyclerView` will know whether to include the last item.

The code looks something like this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItemArray.size() + (shouldShow ? 1 : 0); 
}
```

When the value of `shouldShow` gets updated, I'm not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged()`, but the `RecyclerView` still gets updated properly. But I worry it will eventually cause the `RecyclerView` to crash because of inconsistency. My questions are,

1. Is using a dynamic boolean value in `getItemCount()` a proper way to control `RecyclerView` size?
2. Should I call `notify...()` when the value of this boolean changes?
3. Would my `RecyclerView` crashes for inconsistency because of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.not a problem untill you are passing int in it
2.there is no need to call notifydatasetchanged(we should call them when their is change in adapter data)
3.there will not be any consistency

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what do you mean by 'passing int in it'?

Comment: I mean as getItemCount return int we should pass only int values in it you are passing 1 or 0 based Boolean value it's correct

Answer (score 0):

1.It's ok
2.If you want the last item to be shown right after your boolean variable has changed you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, because `getItemCount()` will not be called by the adapter until recycler view is scrolled.
3.The app can crash if you don't handle all the behaviour. For example you take some item from your `mItemArray` inside `onBindViewHolder()` method, and when `getItemCount()` returns the number bigger than the size of your array, the app will throw `IndexOutOfBoundException`. In this case you should check if position is smaller than size of your array.

```
if (position < mItemArray.size()){
    //you can get item from the array
} else {
    //handle your additional item
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am handling all the action regarding the mItemArray, it is only the boolean that I'm worrying about.